# Kernel issue whilst installing VirtualBox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

On my Fedora 24, after installing and running VirtualBox (from the VB repository) with this command :

```
# dnf install VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.4_110228_fedora24-1.x86_64
$ virtualbox
```

A pop-up window shows me a `Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)`, which is pretty classic according to a search on google. This same error suggest running `/sbin/vboxconfig` :

```
    vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

  yum install kernel-core-devel-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
(The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
  yum install kernel-core-devel
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.
This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

  yum install kernel-core-devel-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
(The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
  yum install kernel-core-devel

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

I noticed that

```
# rpm -qa kernel |sort -V |tail -n 1
kernel-4.6.6-300.fc24.x86_64
# uname -r
4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
```

So I think it may come from that but I don't know how to solve that difference in kernel versions.

I tried, as the `/sbin/rcvboxdrv setup` command suggest :

```
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

  yum install kernel-core-devel-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
(The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
  yum install kernel-core-devel
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.
```

I tried to install, nothing changed.

Another thing, I have a `/usr/src/vboxhost-5.1.4/` folder but :

```
# dkms install vboxhost/5.1.14
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/vboxhost-5.1.14 does not exist.
```

PS: you might ask that `/var/log/vbox-install.log` ("Arrêt" means stop) :

```
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again. Arrêt.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again. Arrêt.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again. Arrêt.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again. Arrêt.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again. Arrêt.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again. Arrêt.
```

Comment: You need to install the header files for running kernel

Comment: You mean through `dnf install kernel-devel` ? It says that the package `kernel-devel-4.6.6-300.fc24.x86_64` is already installed.

Comment: From the messages alone, it looks like you didn't reboot since your kernel update from 4.5.5 to 4.6.6. (That's what the message is hinting at with "if your system is not fully updated".)

Comment: Yes I understood that too, so I tried to reboot several times but ...